# Encode interval as string for intersection query

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, database-indexes, z-order, spatial-index

The goal is to check if two intervals intersect one another. Easy... right? Just plug this guy in and we can move on?

```js
intersects = itemStart < queryEnd && queryStart < itemEnd
```

Not so fast, we have the following constraints:

- We cannot use the candidate item's interval directly during the intersection check. We must pre-process the interval `[itemStart, itemEnd] => encodedItem`. The encoded item interval must be either a number or a string. We can however use the `[queryStart, queryEnd]` separately or not during the check.
- When performing the intersection check we are limited to the following operations: `beginsWith`, `between`. No further boolean operators can be applied. (These are limitations of [dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html)).

  - `beginsWith(a, b)` checks whether string a starts with string b.
  - `between(a, b, c)` checks whether a is between b and c. Works with strings and numbers.
- The start and end values of the items are in the range `[0, 3254778254386]`.

In summary, the final intersection check must take the form of one of these two:

```js
intersects = between(encodedItem, encodedQueryStart, encodedQueryEnd)
```

```js
intersects = beginsWith(encodedItem, encodedQuery)
```

Perhaps there is a mathematical proof that flattening the 2 dimensional interval into 1 dimension prevents us from inspecting whether the intervals intersect.

---

#### The actual goal

While I am interested in random string problems as a pastime, there is a real world problem underlying this one. I am trying to perform date range intersection queries on a key value database, in this case dynamodb

---

#### What I've tried so far

**Z-Ordering**

I have been looking into geospatial indexes and Z-Ordering which has given me some faith that this is possible. [[0]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-1/)[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)[[2]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-2/)[[3]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries) With Z-ordering you can work out if a query interval contains another by interleaving the interval into a string.

e.g.

```
            itemA = { start: 123, end: 456 }
     encodedItemA = "142536"
            itemB = { start: 111, end: 115 }
     encodedItemB = "111115"
            query = { start: 110, end: 119 }
encodedQueryStart = "111100" // interleave query.start with itself
  encodedQueryEnd = "111199" // interleave query.end with itself
```

Once this preprocessing is done I can do

```
isContained = between(encodedItem, encodedQueryStart, encodedQueryEnd)
isContained = between("142536", "111100", "111199") // returns false ✅
isContained = between("111115", "111100", "111199") // returns true ✅
```

However, "isContained" is not the same as "intersects".

**Redundancy**

The other thing I've explored is expanding every item so that it is no longer an interval but represented by many points facilitating prefix search. e.g.

```
itemA = { start: 123, end: 456 } is inserted as 334 rows:
           itemA1 = 123
           itemA2 = 124
              ...
           itemAN = 456
itemB = { start: 111, end: 115 } is inserted as 5 rows:
           itemB1 = 111
           itemB2 = 112
              ...
           itemBN = 115
query = { start: 110, end: 119 }
encodedQuery = commonPrefix(query.start, query.end) = "11"
intersects = beginsWith("111", "11") // returns false ✅
intersects = beginsWith("123", "11") // returns true ✅
```

This comes with its own trade offs.

---

Is there any other clever wizardry I could try to make this work?

Comment: Out of interest, what solution did you settle on?

Comment: In the end we skipped this problem and decided it was easier for the client to download all the relevant data and do the query on the client