# How to optimize an intersection date range query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have the following table

```
1   id  int4    NO  NULL    "nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)"     NULL
2   first_name  varchar(100)    YES NULL    NULL        NULL
3   last_name   varchar(100)    YES NULL    NULL        NULL
4   start   timestamptz YES NULL    NULL        NULL
5   end timestamptz YES NULL    NULL        NULL
6   bio text    YES NULL    NULL        NULL
```

I've tried creating the following indexes

```
create index foo on users (start);
create index foo2 on users ("start", "end");
```

I've created 1 million random rows. I would like to optimize this query, or at least I would like it to use some indexes

```
explain select * from "users" where "start" < '2021-09-24 01:00:00.000' and "end" > '2018-09-24 01:00:00.000'
```


<sup>Original query was wrong as many commenters pointed out.</sup>

```
explain select * from "users" where "start" <  '2021-09-24 01:00:00.000' and '2021-08-24 01:00:00.000' < "end" ;
```

The output is

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..50520.72 rows=52278 width=238)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..44292.92 rows=21782 width=238)
"        Filter: ((start < '2021-09-24 01:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ('2021-08-24 01:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone < ""end""))"
```

It runs in 2.5 sec, however, my goal is not really to optimize speed. I'm more interested in how the indexes work. Specifically I can see it uses sequential scan. I'm curious what kind of index would actually be suited to such a query. As far as I can see, a B+Tree would not really help in this situation as it's not really possible to encode a date range efficiently into a B+Tree. [I think it reduces to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545717/encode-interval-as-string-for-intersection-query). I've read a litte about covering index but also don't think it applies here?

Maybe I just haven't inserted enough rows though for this to really trouble postgres?

Comment: To me it looks like the `start` and `end` values are backwards. What are you trying to achieve with this query? Add as update to question.

Comment: The main issue with your filtering criteria is that both predicates (`start < '2021-09-24 01:00:00.000'` and also `end > '2018-09-24 01:00:00.000'`) are not selective enough. In other words, each one of them selects a high number of rows. PostgreSQL decides none of them is suitable for an index scan, and performs a heap scan instead. Now, can you set a lower and upper bound to any of those columns, even artificially? If that's the case, then you can promote the use of an index.

Comment: I just noticed. You are selecting 790k rows out of 1 million. In this case (79% rows selected) a heap scan is much more efficient than an index scan.

Comment: Have you tried with a `tztsrange` column and adding GiST index, and then using a range operator/function like `intersection` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV No I have not sounds interesting could you elaborate a bit more in an answer? How do the underlying indexes work?

Comment: Good catch @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL supports range data types - including time ranges, e.g. [TSTZRANGE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html). Range types support GiST indexing (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) and are normally used as [exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) to prevent timeframes overlapping, e.g. when booking time slots for your dentist.

Since your query seems to be of type `Give me all timeframes which DO NOT overlap with the given timeframe` - the range type and Btree_GiST indexing look like a perfect solution.

So instead of 2 columns `start` and `end` you will have one column `[start, end)` - meaning that the time interval is closed on the left and open on the right (`start` is included in the timeframe, but `end` is excluded from it).

Comment: You can also create the index when using two timestamp columns, by indexing the expression that creates a tsrange